# How do I find load history of a Redshift table?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I loaded data that isn't passing QA, and need to go back to a previous day where the data matched QA results. Is there a system table that I can query to see dates where the table was previously loaded or copied from S3?

I'm mostly interested in finding the date information of previous loads.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Substring(querytxt, 5, Regexp_instr(querytxt, ' FROM') - 5),
       querytxt
FROM   stl_query s1,
       stl_load_commits s2
WHERE  s1.query = s2.query
       AND Upper(s1.querytxt) LIKE '%COPY%'
       AND Lower(s1.querytxt) LIKE '%s3://%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these tables all load ( copy) [STL_LOAD_COMMITS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_COMMITS.html)

This table for all load error [STL_LOAD_ERRORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html)

To do rollback, there is no direct process. What we need to do is create copy of data into some _QA_passed table before we do fresh load into table and rename tables if we have some issues.

Other way is if you have date , using which you are loading some data, then you can use delete query to remove , fresh data which is not good and run vacuum  commands to free up space.